# I am getting error when trying to call show method of local notification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to add flutter local notification to my app and I have followed  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/local-notifications-in-flutter/ , but whenever I am trying to call show method of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin I'm getting the following error. I don't know how to resolve it.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Here's the code for Notification Service class

```
  import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

  class NotificationService {
    static final NotificationService _notificationService =
        NotificationService._internal();

    factory NotificationService() {
      return _notificationService;
    }

    NotificationService._internal();

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        const AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker',
            icon: 'app_icon');

    final IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        IOSNotificationDetails();
    //init method
    Future<void> init() async {
      const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
          AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

      final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
          IOSInitializationSettings(
        requestSoundPermission: false,
        requestBadgePermission: false,
        requestAlertPermission: false,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
      );

      final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
          InitializationSettings(
              android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
              iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
              macOS: null);

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
          onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
    }

    void selectNotification(String? payload) {
      //Handle notification tapped logic here
    }

    void onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
        int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) {
      //Handle notification tapped logic here
    }

    //show notification method
    Future<void> showNotification(
        {required String title,
        required String body,
        required String payload}) async {
      NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
          iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: payload);
    }
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.afterdefence.afterdefence1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:label="AfterDefence" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:showWhenLocked="true" android:turnScreenOn="true" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="afterdefence.com" android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
  );
  await NotificationService().init();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```